# Methods to concatenate strings on separate lines

Tags: ruby, string-literals

This produces newlines:

```
%(https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
                          ?ll=80.914207,%2030.328466&radius=200
                          &v=20161201&m=foursquare&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
                          &intent=browse)
```

This produces spaces:

```
"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
 ?ll=80.914207,%2030.328466&radius=200
 &v=20161201&m=foursquare&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
 &intent=browse"
```

This produces one string:

```
"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search"\
"?ll=80.914207,%2030.328466&radius=200"\
"&v=20161201&m=foursquare&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259"\
"&intent=browse"
```

When I want to separate one string on multiple lines to read it better on screen, is it preferred to use the escape character?

My IDE complains that I should use single quoted strings rather than double quoted strings since there is no interpolation.

Comment: JFYI, there are no escape sequences here. Backslash is a "line continuation character" in this context.

Comment: Options 1 and 2 __both__ produce a combination of newlines and spaces. And all three produce one string.

Comment: What if you use single quoted strings in the third example? That way the IDE won't complain :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd put something like this on one line, readability be damned, because the alternatives are going to be problematic. There's no way of declaring a string with whitespace ignored, but you can do this:

```
url = %w[ https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
  ?ll=80.914207,%2030.328466&radius=200
  &v=20161201&m=foursquare&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259
  &intent=browse
].join
```

Where you explicitly remove the whitespace.

I'd actually suggest avoiding this whole mess by properly composing this URI:

```
uri = url("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search",
  ll: [ 80.914207,30.328466 ],
  radius: 200,
  v: 20161201,
  m: 'foursquare',
  categoryId: '4d4b7105d754a06374d81259',
  intent: 'browse'
)
```

Where you have some kind of helper function that properly encodes that using URI or other tools. By keeping your parameters as data, not as encoded strings, for as long as possible you make it easier to spot bugs as well as make last-second changes to them.

Comment: And in Rails, that helper function calls to_query on the hash))

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @tadman definitely suggests the proper way to do it; I’ll post another approach just for the sake of diversity:

```
query = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search"
        "?ll=80.914207,%2030.328466&radius=200"
        "&v=20161201&m=foursquare&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259"
        "&intent=browse"
```

Yes, without any visible concatenation, 4 strings in quotes one by one in a row. This example won’t work in `irb`/`pry` (due to it’s REPL nature,) but the above is the *most efficient* way to concatenate strings in ruby without producing any intermediate result.

---

Contrived example to test in `pry`/`irb`:

```
value = "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: Why didn't anyone mention the most obvious way, the _actual_ concatenation via `+`? Requires no further explanation, acceptable overhead, works in most any language. :shrug: